# Deploying static HTML page to Heroku with PHP header

Tags: php, html, heroku

I am attempting to post the following static HTML page on Heroku (getting around its inability to host static pages by using PHP). Heroku accepts the app but it won't load in a browser (I get a 500 message). I have renamed my file "index.php" and have loaded an empty composer.json file with it as well...

```
<?php require (‘home.html’);?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<h1>test page </h1>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Are pasting your code, straight ? Because your single quotes are quite strange.

Comment: Was taking it from the PHP docs, which have <?php
require('somefile.php');
?>

Comment: Not the same simple quotes